# python retrieve integer value of tag with minidom

Tags: python, xml, tags, minidom

I would like to recover the integer value of a tag

```
from xml.dom import minidom

docXML = minidom.parse('/root/Desktop/doc.xml')

node = docXML.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]

value = node.firstChild.data 

     " return value is 5.22%"

str1 = value.split('%') 

    "return [u'\n5.22', u'\n']"

finalvalue = ''.join(str1) 

     "return 5.22"
```

but if I would to convert this string character

```
convert = int(finalvalue)
```

I got the following error

```
"ValueError  invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.22 ' "
```

When I use the split method I get the following result:

`[u'\n5.22', u'\n']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strip()` to remove whitespaces from the string before converting to integer, & use float(the_str) to convert it to float.

```
>>> num_str = '5.22 '
>>> int(num_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.22 '
>>> float(num_str.strip())
5.22
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro.you are my savior ^^